# Largest 5-digit palindrome in base 16, where each digit appears at most twice

Tags: mathematics, number-property, palindrome

What is the largest number $ x $ such that $ x_{16}, $ i.e. $ x $ in base 16, is a 5-digit long palindrome, where each digit appears at most twice? A palindrome is a number that reads the same forward as it does backward, such as 737 or 24542.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this a puzzle you created yourself? If not, please [edit] in a source (such as a link). We have an attribution policy, and unsourced puzzles will be closed and perhaps deleted.

Comment: @bobble It's Purely original, for a class I'm teaching!

Comment: Isn't the answer completely trivial? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @loopywalt it is... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems pretty simple, but is the answer

> 1043951?

This number in base 16 is

> FEDEF, which is the largest five-digit palindrome in base 16 where each digit appears at most twice.